# Binding a matrix to datagrid

Tags: silverlight, binding

I have a Datagrid called previewTable.

I have a collection of collections of strings which represents the table data:

```
ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>> tableData
```

I also have a collection of strings which represent columns headers:

```
ObservableCollection<string> columnsHeaders
```

I need to create columns using the columns headers collection, I achieve this here:

```
        foreach (string columnName in columnsHeaders)
        {
            DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
            column.Header = columnName;
            previewTable.Columns.Add(column);
        }
```

Now I need to bind the table to the data.
The problem is:

```
previewTable.ItemsSource = table
```

Doesn't work.

I always have 9 column headers and each collection size in the data is 9.

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Some additional classes:

```
public class EntityDataRow
{
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}

public class RowItemsConverter : IValueConverter //converter for binging
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            var list = (List<string>) value;
            var index = (Int32) parameter;
            return list[index];
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And this is your code (data is a list of EntityRow)

```
                var headers = data[0].Items;
                data.RemoveAt(0);

                PreviewGrid.Columns.Clear();
                PreviewGrid.ItemsSource = data;
                for (var i = 0; i < headers.Count; i++)
                {
                    var column = new DataGridTextColumn { Header = headers[i] };
                    var binding = new Binding("Items");
                    var converter = new RowItemsConverter();
                    binding.Converter = converter;
                    binding.ConverterParameter = i;
                    column.Binding = binding;
                    PreviewGrid.Columns.Add(column);
                }
```

Comment: forgot to mention, in my example the variable 'data' already has all headers in the first row

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexers in bindings so the following ought to work:-

```
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string columnName in columnsHeaders)
        {
            DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
            column.Header = columnName;
            column.Binding = new Binding("[" + i.ToString(); + "]");
            previewTable.Columns.Add(column);
            i += 1;
        }
```